# Visual-testing: how can I assess the code coverage?

Tags: vue.js, testcafe, visual-testing

I would like to know if there is a way to assess code coverage doing visual testing ?

For instance it will be a formula like ...

```
CodeCoverage = NumberOfViewsGenerated / TotalViewsPossible
```

To be more clear,
let's take the code at https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_dropdown_text

We have two possibles views

**view1**

[image: view1]

and **view2**

[image: view2]

If the visual testing process takes just *view1* we should get a *code coverage* of **50%**

I am using testcafe with Javascript/Typescript, and the frontend is generated using Vue.js